# Popen.stdout.readline() blocks in Python 2 but not Python 3

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, popen

I have this Python code:

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def find_line_number(s):
  s1 = str.split(s, '<string>(')
  if len(s1) <= 1:
     return None
  num = str.split(str.split(s, '<string>(')[1], ')')[0]
  return int(num)

def run_code(s):
  res = []
  p = Popen(['python', 'pdb_runner.py', s], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
  s1 = str(p.stdout.readline()
  p.stdin.write('dir()\n')
  p.stdin.flush()
  s = str(p.stdout.readline())
  p.stdout.flush()
  initvars = str.split(str.split(str.split(s, '[\'')[1], '\']')[0], '\', \'')
  initvars.append('__return__')
  res.append({'line': find_line_number(s1), 'vars': {}})
  return res
```

pdb_runner.py:

```
import pdb
import sys

d = pdb.Pdb()
d.run(sys.argv[1])
```

pdb_runner.py is just the wrapper around pdb which will execute the code.

This code works fine in Python 3 (Windows) but blocks in Python 2 (also Windows).

Is there any solution to make this works in Python 2?

Comment: This code actually doesn't work in Python 3. You didn't call `Popen` with `universal_newlines=True`, so `p.stdin` is a `BufferedWriter` and `p.stdout` is a `BufferedReader`. Please post tested code.

Comment: Yes, the simple instrction like run_code("print('a')") or run_code("for i in range(0, 2):\n  print(i)") works.

Comment: `p.stdin.write('dir()\n')` will fail in Python 3: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`.

Comment: Oops, I forgot the leading b, it should be p.stdin.write(b'dir()\n')

Comment: OK, then I hope you know that `str(p.stdout.readline())` doesn't decode the `bytes` using a default encoding in Python 3. It just gets the repr, e.g. `str(b'abc\x81') == "b'abc\\x81'"`.

Comment: Those problems aside, the blocking problem can be addressed by starting Python with unbuffered I/O, e.g. `p = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', 'pdb_runner.py', s], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)`.

Comment: there is no point to call `p.stdout.flush()` here. Unrelated: Please don't call `str()` on a `bytes` object; use `.decode('ascii')` method instead (or pass `universal_newlines=True` to `Popen` to enable text mode). Don't use `str.split(s, sep)`, use `s.split(sep)` instead. Anyway it is not how you should run a debugger, use `python -mpdb your_script.py` instead.